# Detecting when a user is about to delete a row in a table view in ios

Tags: ios, uitableview

In iOS a user can initiate deleting an item from a table view either by swiping the item to the left or putting the table view in edit mode and clicking a 'banned' button that has appeared next to the item.

When the user swipes the item the `tableView:willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:` method gets called. But this doesn't occur when the user clicks the 'banned' button.

How do I detect when the user has clicked the 'banned' button next to an item?

Comment: What do you mean with banned button? Is this a custom button?

Comment: @Alex It's the 'deletion control' shown in this documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html . When you click it the item slides left and reveals the 'real' delete button which will actually remove the item.

Answer (score 0):

<s>The delegate method that gets called when the user clicks the button is [`tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView%3acommitEditingStyle%3aforRowAtIndexPath%3a).</s>

This sounds like a bug in UITableView - try filing a radar at [bugreport.apple.com](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: Doesn't that only get called when the user confirms the delete? I want to get notified when the user clicks the 'show delete' button on the left, before they click the actual revealed delete button on the right.

Comment: Ah, sorry - I had assumed that "Banned" was a custom title for the delete button.